# Is this inference about Maxwell's 3rd equation correct?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

Am I correct in inferring that a changing magnetic field around a loop of wire produces an electric field perpendicular to that changing magnetic field, which itself `induces` current in the wire?

[image]

Comment: The time derivative of the magnetic field is _identical_ to to the rotation of the electric field.

Comment: yes, this is correct (assuming there are no other currents) correct. it is precisely the way electromagnetic induction works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction . It is as if the induced current "tries" to preserve the flux

Answer (score 0):

Induced electric field isn't necessarily perpendicular to magnetic field. Direction of induced electric field depends on distribution of electric current that produces the magnetic field.